# askWithList on Actions on Google

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm following the sample code for Action on Google responses at the following link:

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses

I want the list response to appear when the user initiates the text intent, but all I get is "Your App isn’t responding right now. Try again soon." Here is the code that I'm using (it's copy and paste for the most part from the link):

```
function textIntent(app) {
    app.askWithList(app.buildRichResponse()
        .addSimpleResponse('Alright')
        .addSuggestions(
            ['Basic Card', 'List', 'Carousel', 'Suggestions']),
        // Build a list
        app.buildList('Things to learn about')
        // Add the first item to the list
        .addItems(app.buildOptionItem('MATH_AND_PRIME',
          ['math', 'math and prime', 'prime numbers', 'prime'])
          .setTitle('Math & prime numbers')
          .setDescription('42 is an abundant number because the sum of its ' +
            'proper divisors 54 is greater…')
        )
        // Add the second item to the list
        .addItems(app.buildOptionItem('EGYPT',
          ['religion', 'egypt', 'ancient egyptian'])
          .setTitle('Ancient Egyptian religion')
          .setDescription('42 gods who ruled on the fate of the dead in the ' +
            'afterworld. Throughout the under…')
        )
        // Add third item to the list
        .addItems(app.buildOptionItem('RECIPES',
          ['recipes', 'recipe', '42 recipes'])
          .setTitle('42 recipes with 42 ingredients')
          .setDescription('Here\'s a beautifully simple recipe that\'s full ' +
            'of flavor! All you need is some ginger and…')
        )
    );

}

let actionMap = new Map();
actionMap.set(app.StandardIntents.MAIN, mainIntent);
actionMap.set(app.StandardIntents.TEXT, textIntent);

app.handleRequest(actionMap);
```

Here is my action.json:

```
{
    "actions": [
     {
        "description": "Default Welcome Intent",
        "name": "MAIN",
        "fulfillment": {
            "conversationName": "welcome"
        },
        "intent": {
            "name": "actions.intent.MAIN"
        }
     },
    ],

    "conversations": {
        "welcome": {
            "name": "welcome",
            "url": "https://example.com"
        },
    }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using api.ai or gactions? If gactions, can you post your actions.json with any sensitive information masked? Have you confirmed that your webhook is getting called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using Actions version 2 features, but the actions.json package isn't specifying a version, so it defaults to version 1.

The "conversations" section of actions.json should look something like:

```
"conversations": {
    "welcome": {
        "name": "welcome",
        "url": "https://example.com",
        "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
    },
}
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you so much, I didn't even know that was a thing!