# Actions on Google simulator not using SDK version 2

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm currently working with an action package that declares it will handle the following intents:

- actions.intent.MAIN
- actions.intent.TEXT
- actions.intent.OPTION

I've started with the first two, and proxying this to my own NLP/response gathering I'm able to get basic functionality working. I'm now trying to move forward with showing the user lists using [askWithList](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/ActionsSdkApp#askWithList). My Action Package is defined as follows:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "name": "MAIN",
            "fulfillment": {
                "conversationName": "JamesTest"
            },
            "intent": {
                "name": "actions.intent.MAIN"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "TEXT",
            "fulfillment": {
                "conversationName": "JamesTest"
            },
            "intent": {
                "name": "actions.intent.TEXT"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "OPTION",
            "fulfillment": {
                "conversationName": "JamesTest"
            },
            "intent": {
                "name": "actions.intent.OPTION"
            }
        }
    ],
    "conversations": {
        "JamesTest": {
            "name": "JamesTest",
            "url": "myngrok"
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to respond with `askWithList` and test in the simulator I get the following error:

```
{
  "name": "ResponseValidation",
  "subDebugEntry": [{
    "name": "MalformedResponse",
    "debugInfo": "expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0]: intent 'actions.intent.OPTION' is only supported for version 2 and above."
  }]
}
```

Per the documentation my understanding was that all projects created after May 17 2017 would be using version 2 SDK by default. I also cannot seem to find any indication that I would be able to explicitly declare what version I would like to use in the Action Package definition.

Has anyone run into this? Is this just a limitation of the simulator, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though there is an undocumented (at least I can't find it) field in the `conversations` block called `fulfillmentApiVersion` that must be set to `2` in your actions package. Answer sourced from here: [askWithList on Actions on Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311755/askwithlist-on-actions-on-google)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing something not in the least bit obvious. {: The documentation for this is [somewhat hidden](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/ConversationFulfillment) and the `gactions` command still generates a version 1 json file.

The action package must explicitly indicate the version that it is using, otherwise it will be assumed to be using version 1.

To specify version 2, your "conversations" section should look something like:

```
"conversations": {
    "JamesTest": {
        "name": "JamesTest",
        "url": "myngrok",
        "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
    }
}
```

Note the "fulfillmentApiVersion" parameter.